# twilio API: Make a function sending SMSs with python

Tags: python, api, twilio

I successfully made a python script that sends SMS to my verified phone number with the Twilio API.
This is the code:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "the sid"
auth_token = "the token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)


to = "+the number" # Replace with your phone number
from_ = "+number" # Replace with your Twilio number
message = client.messages.create(to,from_,body="the message")
```

It must be fairly simple but .... how can I wrap this up in a nice function so the only thing that I have to provide is the body variable??

Like this: send_sms(body="whatever")

I tried to do it like this but the create function complains:

```
def sendsms(body="vsdvs"):
    # Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
    account_sid = "fgdfgdfg"
    auth_token = "dfgdfgdfg"
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)


    to = "6345354" # Replace with your phone number
    from_ = "43534534" # Replace with your Twilio number
    message = client.messages.create(to,from_,body)

sendsms()
```

The error I get is:

```
message = client.messages.create(to,from_,body)
TypeError: create() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `message = client.messages.create(to,from_,body)` as `message = client.messages.create(to=to,from_=from_,body=body)`

See the function signature of messages.create() function [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py#L95).

```
class Messages(ListResource):
    name = "Messages"
    key = "messages"
    instance = Message

    def create(self, from_=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Create and send a Message.

        :param str to: The destination phone number.
        :param str `from_`: The phone number sending this message
            (must be a verified Twilio number)
        :param str body: The message you want to send,
            limited to 1600 characters.
        :param list media_url: A list of URLs of images to include in the
            message.
        :param status_callback: A URL that Twilio will POST to when
            your message is processed.
        :param str application_sid: The 34 character sid of the application
            Twilio should use to handle this phone call.
        """
        kwargs["from"] = from_
        return self.create_instance(kwargs)
```

You passed to, from_ and body as a positional arguments but the create function takes only two arguments(one default and 'self') and the rest has to be passed as keyword arguments. This is the reason why the traceback says that the function takes only 2 arguments(self and from_) while you passed 4 (self, to, from_, body).

Comment: Yep... You need to pass keyword arguments - create(from_=from, body=body) instead of regular Python arguments - create(from, body)

Comment: Thank you very much.It's ok now. I really struggle to understand the * and ** structure.